# Changing iterative algorithm to recursive in C

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

Hey I'm a newbie in programming and I don't have much experience with recursive algorithms, I'm working on a simple board game for myself and I have to search for '2's in a 2d array and replace the '1's in their left, right and below, if they exist ofc.

Now here's the code ad my problem:

```
void check_board(char **arr, int grid_size)
{
int v, b;  // to check fillment
for(v=0; v < grid_size; v++)
{
    for(b=0; b < grid_size; b++)
    {
        if(arr[v][b]=='2' )
        {
            if(arr[v+1][b]=='1')
            {
                arr[v+1][b]='2';

            }
            if(arr[v][b+1]=='1')
            {
                arr[v][b+1]='2';

            }
            if(arr[v][b-1]=='1')
            {
                arr[v][b-1]='2';

            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

This is my function that checks the array through iteration, but it takes too long to execute for big sized boards and I want to avoid that, so I guess changing it to recursive will make it faster. That's where I'm stuck, I couldn't find a way to change this algorithm to a recursive one.

I don't want written codes from you, as I try to learn coding, but I need some clues/tips if possible to get me started. Thanks in advance for your help and sorry if this question is a bad one.

Comment: I don't know why recursive might be quicker, but there are (at least) two essential actions required: ensure that there is an exit clause so you don't get infinite recursion, and find a mechanism to prevent visiting the same square twice - such as in a `floodfill` paint algorithm.

Comment: I doubt that a recursive algorithm will be faster. Its code may be shorter, but the speed won't change, to my mind. Moreover, it might even decrease since to run a recursive function your computer will need to copy lots of data around.

Comment: Before making it faster, make it correct. None of those neighbours  (`arr[v][b-1]`, `arr[v][b+1]`, ...) is guaranteed to exist. You are reading and writing outside of your allocated data. Also, why check only 3 neighbours?

Comment: Also perhaps before learning recursion it might be good to learn how to use real 2D arrays. What you are using here is only an emulation of such via an array of pointers. Changing this could really gain you speed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how a recursive solution would be faster than an iterative solution for this problem.

Usually recursion performs worse on languages which doesn't have a good support for them (eg. non functional languages). This is true for C because recursion brings a lot of overhead with her:

- a lot of function calls
- stack space reservation for activation records

Recursion makes sense in C where the alternative would be to manage a recursive structure by the code itself, in all problems that require to keep track of state, because it will be done automatically by the nature of recursion itself. Or makes sense because it is usually able to express in little code an elegant solution to a problem, but has nothing to do with efficiency.

In any case a recursive solution requires a base case and a recursive step, it would look something like:

```
void recursive_check_board(char **board, int size, int x, int y)
{
  if (x == size-1 && y == size-1) // base case
    return;
  else // recursive step
  {
    // set down, left, right to 2 if needed

    recursive_check_board(board, size, x+1, y);
    recursive_check_board(board, size, x, y+1);
    recursive_check_board(board, size, x+1, y+1);
  }
}
```